# What would cause the resource passed to mysql_fetch_object() to be invalid?

Tags: php, warnings, fetch

I got a warning in php as follows

> Warning: mysql_fetch_object(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in E:\Program Files\VertrigoSer\www\b.php on line 16

My program is:

```
<?php
$connection=mysql_connect("localhost","root","vertrigo");
$db=mysql_select_db("mydb",$connection);

$query="INSERT INTO text VALUES(1003,'PHP','Mcgrowhill','Ivan')";
$r=mysql_query($query);

$query="INSERT INTO book VALUES(201,3,1003)";
$r=mysql_query($query);

$query1="select distinct title from text,book,course where text.isbn=book.isbn and book.cno=course.cno and course.dept='CS'";
$r=mysql_query($query1);

echo"row inserted";

while($row=mysql_fetch_object($r))
{
    echo $row->title;
}

mysql_close($connection);
?>
```

kindly give suggestions that how to solve this problem

Comment: This is an extremely localized problem. However, you have enough information in the answers provided to figure it out. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

If the SQL query returns no result, it could trigger this warning.
Before doing the following,

```
$r=mysql_query($query1);
```

Check if number of rows returned is > 0 with the [mysql_num_rows](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php) function. Also check your query directly to see if it works.

**Stop using the MySQL extension**, it is discouraged. Use [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php) or [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)

Comment: Because `mysql_query()` can return mixed types, it would be even better to check with the `===` or `!==` operator, like this: `if ($r !== false)`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can find out:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO text VALUES(1003,'PHP','Mcgrowhill','Ivan')";
$r = mysql_query($query);
if (!$r) {
    echo mysql_error();
}

$query = "INSERT INTO book VALUES(201,3,1003)";
$r = mysql_query($query);
if (!$r) {
    echo mysql_error();
}

$query1 = "select distinct title from text, book, course where text.isbn = book.isbn and book.cno = course.cno and course.dept = 'CS'";
$r = mysql_query($query1);
if (!$r) {
    echo mysql_error();
} else {
    echo"row inserted";

    while($row = mysql_fetch_object($r)) {
        echo $row->title;
    }
}

mysql_close($connection); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Text** is a **Reserved** word of mysql so use alias and try it

Like

```
$query1="select distinct title from text as t,book as b,course as c where t.isbn=b.isbn and b.cno=c.cno and c.dept='CS'";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this.

```
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);
```

Or

```
if (!$result)
   die("mySQL error: ". mysql_error());
```